# Align text in table cell to right in PHPWord 0.12.0

Tags: phpword

I am using PHPWord 0.12.0. I have a table created, but cannot seem to align text in the cells. Here is my code for the specific line:

```
$table->addCell(1540, array('bgColor' => 'dddddd'))->addText(htmlspecialchars("Testing", array('align' => 'right')));
```

I have also tried:

```
$table->addCell(1540, array('bgColor' => 'dddddd', 'align' => 'right'))->addText(htmlspecialchars("Testing"));
```

The background color shows up fine, but I cannot get the alignment to work. There is no "align" in the specs for a table cell, so what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked https://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html?highlight=alignment?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the manual, that's how I know there is no "align" in the specs for table cell.

Comment: Does it work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020814/formating-a-text-in-a-table-cell-with-phpword-e-g-bold-font-size-e-t-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would seem that in order to use a paragraph style that PHPWord also requires a font style. So, with a font style defined I can simply use:

```
$table->addCell(1540, array('bgColor' => 'dddddd'))->addText(htmlspecialchars("Testing the alignment"), $myfontstyle, array('align' => 'right'));
```

And it works. Of course, you must have defined a font style called $myfontstyle earlier in your code (or place the array inside the code as I did for the paragraph style).

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. The documentation isn't very clear.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer kojow7, YES i agree with you that documentation is not very clar.. @PawelGumiela