# Set font style to table with addHtml in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I am using a table with `addHtml` method to export HTML to docx file in phpWord. But the font of text is Times New Roman (font-size 12), meanwhile, the font should be Arial (font-size 10) by default. I did not set anything in code. I also tried something but it seems not to work. Here is my code:

```php
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('modules/admin/views/customers/resume_tpl.docx');

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Arial');
$phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(10);

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$wordTable = $section->addTable();
$wordTable->addRow();
$cell = $wordTable->addCell();                                
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($cell, str_replace("&","&amp;", $model[self_assessment]));  // $model[self_assessment] is the HTML text

// $templateProcessor->setDefaultFontName('Arial');
// $templateProcessor->setDefaultFontSize(10);
                  
$templateProcessor->setComplexBlock('assess', $wordTable);
```

All I want is to set font to 'Arial' and font-size 10.

Comment: Do you want to set the whole DOCX document to become 'Arial' size-10 or just the content of the new table ?

Comment: I want just the content of table is Arial - 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of figured it out, although I don't like this way :v. Because my text is from CK Editor, so it has HTML format. I just add css style to HTML and it works. Something like this:

```php
$model[self_assessment] = str_replace("&","&amp;", $model[self_assessment]);

$assess = str_replace("<p>", "<p style='font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;'>", $model[self_assessment]);
$assess = str_replace("<ul>", "<ul style='font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;'>", $assess);
$assess = str_replace("<ol>", "<ol style='font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;'>", $assess);
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the `addText()` method with your code and it does change the font-name and font-size of the table, by reference post here [Formatting a text in a table cell with PHPWord e.g. bold, font, size e.t.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020814/formatting-a-text-in-a-table-cell-with-phpword-e-g-bold-font-size-e-t-c)

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('test.docx');

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$wordTable = $section->addTable();

$wordTable->addRow();
$wordTable
  ->addCell()
  ->addText(
    str_replace("&","&amp;", "HTML Texting"),
    array(
      'name' => 'Arial',
      'size' => 10,
    );
  );
                  
$templateProcessor->setComplexBlock('assess', $wordTable);

$templateProcessor->saveAs('result.docx');
```

Hope it helps!

---

And I think this sample might help out for you too
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_40_TemplateSetComplexValue.php

Comment: because my text is from CK Editor, so it has HTML format. Therefore, I must use addHtml to keep the format. I figured it out. I will post the answer. Thank you for your idea

Comment: Glad that you found the solution finally :) Happy coding !